# How to add a new function to an already existing model class

Tags: php

Is there a way to append a new function to a PDO class system?
The problem I encounter is that the class closes of with }. Which means I can't append code to it.

I need to replicate this function and that inside of class HomeModel

```
 class HomeModel extends Model{
    public function blank(){
       $this->query('SELECT * FROM blank WHERE id=1');
       $rows = $this->resultSet();

       $update = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    

       if($update['edit']) {

           $update['last_update'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 hours'));
           $newTime = $update['last_update'];
           $body = $update['blank_body'];
           $this->query('UPDATE blank SET blank_body="'.$body.'", last_update="'.$newTime.'" WHERE id=1');
           $this->execute();

            //redirect
            header('Location: '.ROOT_URL.'#blank');

       }
    return($rows);

   }

  ** APPEND A NEW FUNCTION **      

}
```

I need to do this to my controller class as well but that one is basically the same as my model above.

I tried to make a str_replace. Well this worked on a page without a class( just a normal PHP file) I wasn't able to replicate it inside the class. It doesn't recognize anything but functions.

A friend told me the smartest way is to put it as an array but without any good explanation.

I'm pretty sure this is possible but I'm getting a bit clueless.

Comment: Why not just extend the class?

Comment: @MarceloStaudt You mean something like this? $var = new Class? Or make another extension of Home: Class blank extends Home?

Comment: I mean `class YourHomeModel extends HomeModel
{
 function yourNewfunction(){ /* ... */ }
}`

Comment: @MarceloStaudt Well my intention was to keep that page clean and push everything under 1 class. Otherwise, I need to make a new class extends Homemodel for each page I make. You can argue the way I want makes it even a bigger mess because you can't distinguish the files anymore. Nonetheless I will give it a shot.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now. But what does those functions supposed to do? Are you sure you can't solve your problem by passing arguments on a generic function? What you are trying to do really does sound like a mess.

Comment: @MarceloStaudt Thx for the feedback. My friend was a bit clearer now and said I was doing it totally wrong. As you said the way I wanted will make it more of a mess. Makes it unclear and convoluted for myself and also future me. This makes this question out of place because I doubt this will be helpful to anyone.